# Query IsDeleted = 0 on all tables

Tags: sql, view, left-join

In my database, I have 9 tables and I need to create a view.

This view will eventually query all tables. The one consistency here is that there is a column in all tables for IsDeleted. How do I run a query to check the column in all tables where IsDeleted = 0?

The three tables are: Customers, County, Country

**This is my View:**

```
CREATE VIEW vwTEST
AS
SELECT
    Cus.CustomerId,
    Cus.FirstName,
    Cus.LastName,
    Cty.CountyName,
    Cry.CountryName
FROM
    Customers Cus
LEFT JOIN
    County Cty
ON  
    Cus.CountyId = Cty.CountyId
WHERE 
    Cus.IsDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN
    Country Cry
ON
    Cus.CountryId = Cry.CountryId
WHERE 
    Cry.IsDeleted = 0
```

[Table formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHFWu.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what is the result you want. If you want to have also those customers that are not deleted but have a County or a Country deleted, then you have to make subqueries to select only the undeleted records and join:

```
CREATE VIEW vwTEST
AS
SELECT
    Cus.CustomerId,
    Cus.FirstName,
    Cus.LastName,
    Cty.CountyName,
    Cry.CountryName
FROM
    Customers Cus
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
   County.CountyId,
   County.CountyName
   FROM County
   WHERE County.IsDeleted = 0) AS Cty ON Cus.CountyId = Cty.CountyId
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
   Country.CountryId,
   Country.CountryName
   FROM Country
   WHERE Country.IsDeleted = 0) AS Cry ON Cus.CountryId = Cry.CountryId
WHERE Cus.IsDeleted = 0;
```

The result (here with all the fields) will be:

[image]

If you only want rows where nothing is deleted, then it is just:

```
SELECT
*
FROM Customers Cus
LEFT JOIN County Cty ON  Cus.CountyId = Cty.CountyId
    LEFT JOIN Country Cry ON Cus.CountryId = Cry.CountryId
WHERE Cus.IsDeleted = 0 AND Cty.IsDeleted = 0 AND Cry.IsDeleted = 0;
```

and the result will be:

[image]

My test dataset, as a result of the JOINs without any WHERE condition as:

```
SELECT
*
FROM Customers Cus
LEFT JOIN County Cty ON  Cus.CountyId = Cty.CountyId
    LEFT JOIN Country Cry ON Cus.CountryId = Cry.CountryId;
```

is:

[image]

Regards

Comment: Thanks White Feather, I think I know what your thinking. When I apply your query I get. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure vwTEST, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure vwTEST, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'."

Comment: I changed it, there was an error. I am updating again with an alternative in few minutes.

Comment: Thanks very much @White Feather, this is brilliant, I have tested it against my DB. This is excellent. This is from my college assignment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you outer (ie `LEFT`) join a table but have a condition on that table in the `WHERE` clause, you effectively turn the join into an *inner* join. This due to the fact that where clause conditions are executed *after* then ion is made, but missed joins have all nulls for their columns, so any comparison will fail.

The solution is to move *all* conditions on outer joined tables into the join's `ON` clause, which is executed *as the join is made*.

```
CREATE VIEW vwTEST AS
SELECT
    Cus.CustomerId,
    Cus.FirstName,
    Cus.LastName,
    Cty.CountyName,
    Cry.CountryName
FROM Customers Cus
LEFT JOIN County Cty
ON Cus.CountyId = Cty.CountyId
  AND Cus.IsDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN Country Cry
ON Cus.CountryId = Cry.CountryId
  AND Cry.IsDeleted = 0
```

This query still allows county and country is not join when only deleted rows are available.

It seems like you instinctively knew this, but didn't know the syntax to express it, as all I had to do was change `WHERE` to `AND`.